# Unable to install proj related Python packages in a Linux alpine environment

Tags: python, proj, pyproj, docker

I'm unable to install [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/) or any proj related Python packages such as [geopandas](https://pypi.org/project/geopandas/), in an [alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) dockerized environment, e.g. `[python:3.9.1-alpine3.12][1]`.

Error is, e.g. for pyproj itself here:

```
# pip install -U pyproj

Collecting pyproj>=2.6.1
  Using cached pyproj-3.0.0.post1.tar.gz (663 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpzry1ashr
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-t9aa85lz/pyproj_f26b845284ef4a79b4aa5741d7b58e44
  Complete output (1 lines):
  proj executable not found. Please set the PROJ_DIR variable.    
  For more information see: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
/usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpzry1ashr 
Check the logs for full command output.
```

So I went to the documentation using the provided link at: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html
where one can read:

[image: proj install notice]

I do not fully understand what this means, especially what the 'manylinux2010' is?

Does it mean it is not *installable* into an alpine Linux?

Notice, I have installed these packages with [apk](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) prior to installing Python packages:

```
proj proj-dev proj-datumgrid geos-dev gdal gdal-dev gdal-tools
```

maybe I only missed one... but which?

Comment: For the manylinux2010 part: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0571/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/767, `proj-util` is the missing package.

Based on the version compatibility matrix: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/installation.html#installing-from-source (see figure below), you have to use `pyproj<3` with the version of PROJ you are using. Once `proj-util` includes PROJ>=7.2, you can upgrade to pyproj 3+.

[image: pyproj compatibility matrix]